# Why is the system asking me to wait a day before asking a question, and when does that day start?

Tags: discussion

Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Skeptics!  If your account is new, the system might be placing a limit on how fast you can ask questions as part of an anti-spam measure.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer to your question in our [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help)

[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

In addition, a day is defined as starting at 00:00 UTC as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)